# Checking service status with php on linux?

Tags: php, linux, service

I'm trying to read status of a service using php7 on Debian 9.
The command is simple:

```
sudo -u root -S service openvpn@debideb status < /var/www/html/.htpass
```

I do get desired result when I test it in terminal:

```
openvpn@debideb.service - OpenVPN connection to debideb
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-25 06:17:15 PDT; 1h 2min ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 5049 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-debideb --status /run/openvpn/debideb.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn -
 Main PID: 5051 (openvpn)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@debideb.service
           └─5051 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-debideb --status /run/openvpn/debideb.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config
```

however,when I do it through www-data I get following results:
`passthru()` returns `int(1)`;
`shell_exec()` returns `NULL`;
`exec()` and `system()` return `string("")`;

Where did I screw up?

Comment: does www-data have access to execute this command? You execute it with sudo so I don't think it does.

Comment: Ok now I understand it's a user:group thing. I have to add www-data to sudoers, I think

Comment: this will work but in terms of security this is really bad idea

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know any better at this point. Adding www-data to sudoers seem have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a CRON to check service status and output the result to some kind of output format then read the output file from the web server user. This way you could isolate the user running the CRON from the webserver user, and make this a lot more secure.

It's a really bad idea to have an `exec` call in your PHP at all, let alone when the web server has root permissions (which you'd need here.)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Allenph.

However, if there's any reason to exec() some script from your PHP code, maybe you can install *sudo*, then add *www-data* to sudoers and restrict it to execute just only the script you need to be run with no password.

In /etc/sudoers (thinking on the fly, please, review the syntax with some docs):

```
www-data  NOPASWD:/path/to/my/script.sh
```

The permissions for the script should be set to something like 500 or 700 and the owner should be *root* (never *www-data*).